# Apache Camel: keeping filtered messages

Tags: java, routes, apache-camel

Say I have a queue containing the messages `A`, `A`, `B`, `A`, `B`, `A`. I'd like to log+drop all `B` messages, but I'd like to *keep* all `A` messages untouched. So basically I need some type of *ignore* functionality, rather than a *discarding* filter.

If that's not available I probably need to do something similar to:

```
from("jms:queue:from")
    .filter(header("head").isEqualTo("B")).to("log:com.acme?level=INFO").end()
    .to("jms:queue:from");
```

This type of thing seems like a fairly common pattern? How do people usually do this type of thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [choice](http://camel.apache.org/routes.html) is a better option than filter

```
    from("jms:queue:from")
    .choice()
        .when(header("head").isEqualTo("B")).to("log:com.acme?level=INFO")
        .otherwise().to("jms:queue:from")
    .end()
```

Comment: If I'd be able to control the JMS headers, I could have used [JMS Message Selectors](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bncer/index.html)...